# The approval system isn't working for unpopular topics

Tags: discussion, documentation, proposed-changes

I get that we want some kind of validation of edits made to "examples" but currently the less popular tags are not getting approved (or not in a timely manner). I edited some examples in [sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sitecore/topics) to add extra details this morning. 6 hours later no one has looked at my edits and they are **still** waiting approval.

The approval system I feel works well for popular subject like JavaScript, C#, etc. But the less glamourous tags are just going to get ignored.

As a 10K rep user why do my edits need approval at all? I can edit questions and answers at will, why is docs different?

Comment: Yes, this is pretty frustrating, especially since I'm so used to the Q&A instant edit workflow.  There's basically three active people looking at [flask], and we have to keep pinging each other in a chat room to get things done.

Comment: Well I can't access the chat room at work so I don't even have that option...

Comment: Even for popular tags like C++, many edits take 6 hours to be approved

Comment: And in popular tags, there might be *too many* people editing things, stepping on each other's toes and duplicating *everything*.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I think a review queue for proposed changes would be better.

Comment: So over the weekend all my edits got rejected because *"Rejected due to a conflict with another proposed change"*. Seriously?! So now I have to edit them again and wait another 48hours for someone to reject them again possibly.

Comment: @Liam It would be better as a only 1 edit per example / section at a time. Then there is less duplication, less conflicts, and it's still usable.

Comment: It could also work if you are required to review any other changes for the page you want to edit before you are allowed to edit the page

Comment: @geek1011 the issue is with that is that it it solves the conflict issue but makes the bag log even longer. So some tags will be waiting even longer for approval. Like I said I don't get why anyone over x rep needs approval at all. I don't need approval to edit anything on the Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [changes are afoot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th?cb=1)

> There’s a backlog of about 2,000 proposed changes (vs something like
>   22,000 total changes reviewed). Some of this is too much content from
>   over-enthusiastic users, some of it is presentation in the UX having
>   too much friction, and **some of it is the system limiting trusted users
>   more than it should**. There are planned changes below to address this.