# Documentation Update, July 25th

Tags: discussion, documentation

As part of the Documentation Beta, we’re going to be doing a series of meta posts (and blog posts in all likelihood) with what we’ve learned, and what we’re planning to change accordingly.  See the [next post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331663/80572) in the series.

These posts will normally be about once a week, but since we just launched last Thursday we’ve already got lots to share.

### What we’ve learned

1. Ho-boy, lots of contributions.  We got more activity in 1 day on Stack Overflow than we did in the entirety of the private beta.  Lots and lots of bugs that didn’t come up in our (months of) private testing.  **Accordingly, since Thursday we’ve been focused on bugs.**
2. Reputation needs work.  [Adam already posted some tweaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse), and we’ll have more in the future.  Again we tested in the private beta, and did some additional offline modeling.  The basic model (rep for example upvotes, approved changes, and upvoting answers citing docs) doesn’t seem terribly broken - but the limits (like who gets rep for examples, and how much) definitely need work.  **Expect more reputation tweaks in the coming weeks.**
3. There’s a backlog of about 2,000 proposed changes (vs. something like 22,000 total changes reviewed).  Some of this is too much content from over-enthusiastic users, some of it is presentation in the UX having too much friction, and some of it is the system limiting trusted users more than it should.  **There are planned changes below to address this**.
4. Some topics have way too many examples.  Part of this is because many folks are just trying it out, and adding examples is easy.  Part of it is that the “expected number” of examples isn’t well indicated.  **There’s a planned change below to address this**.  We will also consider capping examples per topic if this continues to be an issue.
5. We haven’t quite figured out how to allocate numbers of outstanding changes a user should be allowed to have, and number of reviews a user should be allowed to do.  For now we have simple daily caps.  We’ll keep an eye on rejection rates, and what gets approved, as the “launch bounce” dies down and tweak accordingly.

### Planned changes

1. **A review queue for Proposed Changes**.  We were hesitant to do this while Documentation hadn’t been merged into Stack Overflow, and uncertain that such a queue would be necessary.  A few days of public beta have shown us otherwise, so this is now on the roadmap.

Here’s a (very early, very rough) mockup of the new queue.

[image: Review Queue]

2. **Tag merges and aliases** for Documentation.  We will be adding a mapping from related tags to “master” tags (like [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-2.7/topics) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python-3.x/topics) are related to the “master” [python](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics)).  Such a mapping will migrate existing topics to the master tag and prevent re-opening the aliased tag for Documentation.  Initially we (Stack Overflow employees) will be doing these by hand; it may be opened to moderators and high rep users up in the future.
3. **A short, optional, “Focus” section** at the top of each topic - sort of like what was [suggested in this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328620/documentation-should-have-an-initial-section).  This section will be used to define the scope of a Topic and should guide contributors with respect to what sorts of examples belong on a topic.  It is explicitly *not a summary* of the topic, but it will help readers get the gist of what they’ll find.

Comment: What about minimum tag score for approving proposed changes? Is that going to be integrated in the review queue in some way? Right now, a lot of  low tag score users are getting their incorrect edits approved, as it only takes 1 approval to make it live.

Comment: @tktsubota minimum tag score is problematic in lower-frequency tags especially, where there are so much fewer people with that tag score.

Comment: Minimum overall rep of 5,000 to add examples without an approval process would be a good idea. Also, why have a queue/approval process for things like fixing simple typos (if at all)?

Comment: @Hack-R I have 15k rep and I do not think I should be allowed to post without approval. Not because I'm not knowledgeable, but everything I add to the docs should be checked. I sometimes word things badly, break the format inadvertently or even may introduce a blatant mistake. I maybe am a core contributor to php-src and to the official manual, but this does not mean I never post mistakes. Documentation has a much higher bar of correctness than normal SO posts, IMO. If it's just simple typos, they're also quickly reviewed by anyone else, it takes barely 10 seconds to review such a proposal…

Comment: @bwoebi How is that any different from Q&A though? We always want everything to be factually correct, well formatted, etc, and there are already lots of tools and gamifications in place to support that (peer editing, voting, etc), but having the 1-user approval process increases quality only the tiniest amount while slowing growth and causing an unsustainable backlog buildup.

Comment: @Hack-R _Documentation has a much higher bar of correctness than normal SO posts, IMO_. Backlog buildup is in my experience not a problem in well-frequented tags. The problem are mostly these statements like "fetch() in a loop is faster than foreach over fetchAll()".  Most people read that and think TIL! … very few people actually have the knowledge to state it's wrong (and even fever check it). Documentation is supposed to be far more authoritative than normal q&a is. It's maybe only a small difference in quality, but an important one. Just like 99.4% and 99.9% are only 0.5% away...

Comment: No mention of a better education process for all to streamline understanding of what should and more importantly shouldn't be documented. The tour and help center are thin. A decent slide presentation or video would help quash useless proposal requests, topics etc and be a point of reference for rejecting  garbage

Comment: @charlietfl I think what should and shouldn't be documented is also a lot a tag specific problem (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329567/documentation-tag-specific-focus) - topics are just solving one part of the problem; in case the topic already exists.

Comment: Love the "Edit & Approve" option. That was desperately needed. I'm assuming the idea is to only apply the additional edit if the parent edit is applied? Would that need reviewed also?

Comment: So y'all are not convinced that we need some sort of commenting or discussion system, then (as suggested http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328895/ and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329173/)?

Comment: @Frank As far as I've seen, people are using chat rooms for that. I agree it's disorganized though.

Comment: One note, just because something isn't listed above doesn't mean it won't be considered in the near future or isn't being considered now. It's just that the team has to start with a manageable set of improvements that can be implemented in a short amount of time before moving on to the next round of updates.

Comment: I don't understand why you think a review queue is necessary. The biggest problem I've seen is not a backlog of suggestions, but rather incorrect suggestions getting approved. A better way to deal with the backlog is what you alluded to in the question: trusting *trusted* users more. We let 20k users edit tag wikis unimpeded; why not do the same for Documentation? Similarly, a single vote from a trusted user should always approve or reject a suggestion, clearing the queue much more quickly. I really dislike a review queue because tag experts should be doing *most* of the reviewing.

Comment: What does "*not a summary*" mean? Is it inappropriate to start a Focus section with e.g. "An **array** is a variable-length contiguous data structure which..."? Isn't that precisely the kind of thing that'd be useful at the *top* of a topic?

Comment: @4castle From what I have seen (in the C++ section) no one is using chat rooms to discuss changes/organization etc. The `C++ Documentation` chat room has been empty since docs started. The general chatroom has people posting about general problems and asking for reviews. But (in C++ at least) I have seen no real communication between contributors.

Comment: Will there be a *review queue* per tag? Because there is no way I am qualified to review most of the tags.

Comment: Is anything being done about the [UI freezing issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329377/documentation-freezing-when-editing)? This seems to be affecting an increasing number of people

Comment: Please consider http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse#comment373354_328703 and similar concerns.

Comment: @Galik yes, you'll be able to filter by tag, or multiple tags and the link from the tag dashboard to the review queue will automatically filter according to the tag you are in.

Comment: What about moving topics from one tag to another? Is that part of Planned Changes #2?

Comment: @TotZam it's a definite need, just didn't make it into this first round of improvements.

Comment: "*Tag merges and aliases for Documentation.*" Wait a second: You [*declined* my request for *exactly this*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328175), then turn around and do it?

Comment: I just browsed a bit through Documentation and I was negatively impressed by the quality of the content. It seems that many contributors have never heard of code comments but at the same time like to copy verbatim from Wikipedia. If it stays like this, Documentation won't be useful.

Comment: Are the meta questions from the beta site still in the process of being moved over? I posted some questions that I still think are valid and discussion worthy, yet I don't see them on this site yet...

Comment: @Trilarion Examples of code should be explained with prose outside of the code blocks, not relegated to code comments.

Comment: @TylerH But code usually contains comments and those I am missing. Also, could we have then code blocks with line numbers (as Github does), so I can refer a bit easier to a specific position in the prose.

Comment: @Trilarion: "*But code usually contains comments and those I am missing.*" Coding style is not universal. There are plenty of people who rarely use comments because they try to write code that's easy to understand and therefore doesn't need them.

Comment: @Trilarion Code contains comments because code doesn't come with a handout of prose explaining what the code does. The ability to include that kind of prose with examples entirely precludes the need for embedded comments, which are never as detailed as prose anyway.

Comment: @TylerH You're absolutely right. The line numbers could be a good idea though. Just to make the prose easier.

Comment: Does anyone know how to un-commit to a docs topic?

Comment: @RayNicholus I just disabled the notifications via the dashboard. There's small grey clickable text next to the headings over requested topics and need improvement.

Comment: @ivarni I'm looking to un-commit to a topic.

Comment: Trying not to kick in a possibly already open door: the only real hangup right now appears to be the overwhelming enthusiasm for the feature.  You have enough, removing the banner from the front page could be sensible.  You can always put it back later.

Comment: Please make reputation a flat award of +5 rep/edit _max_.

Comment: With the proposed review queue will you be adding a reject and edit option?

Comment: Agreed. There needs to be more accountability and recovery for changes. [See this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/revisions/169?exampleId=689) (for example). My ok-example got edited to uselessness, then deleted. A rollback to the previous state and an example improvement request would suffice in that instance.

Comment: I kinda want to see that review queue thing up soon. I've been doing a lot of reviewing and I think I deserve my badges for it ^_^

Comment: What about allow a user to have an additional “outstanding change” if they complete a few reviews?
The review queue should only show me items for tags that I have a lot more upvotes in them most reviewers along with tags that I have edited an example for.

Comment: For tags with <5 votes review turnaround is very low. I think review reputation bar should be proportional to a tag popularity.

Comment: Where did all the bug/feature request posts go from the private beta? I had at least 10 that were open.

Comment: If a video is uploaded about how to write doc ,that help new user to contribute more feature

Comment: Reviewing process sucks. I have submitted some new examples on Sunday and they have not been reviewed yet. And it was a common technology (servlets, jdbc).

Comment: Don't you think a "Related Properties" would be useful for Documentation?

Comment: And I really want a button for the "search topic" field...

Comment: My main impressions of Documentation so far are also my main worries: 1. plagiarism (from official documentation, existing popular unofficial documentation sites, Wikipedia, SO itself) and 2. the "is it Documentation or is it Examples?" question, with its side issues 2i. "isn't SO already the dream Examples site?" and 2ii. what about plagiarized examples? ¶ I wasn't in the private beta, but I assume 1 discussed there and internally. Since examples are a key part of Documentation, I assume 2ii has also. And many people bring up 2 below. I'd love to see all four addressed in a future update post

Comment: Will there be a Documentation Update July 32nd?

Answer (score 205):

> Note: This is now a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329677/incorrect-information-in-documentation-the-solution). If you agree, please upvote!

### The Problem

There is an issue right now with incorrect information being added to documentation.

**Why?**

- 1 rep users with 0 tag score can propose an incorrect change
- 100 rep users with 0 tag score can accept an incorrect change
- Only 1 user needs to accept the change before it goes live
- It takes 2 users to determine a change is incorrect and reject it

### Current Proposed Solutions

**Minimum tag score or tag badge required for contributing**

- Pros: Requires some knowledge of the tag being contributed on, not filling the review queue with incorrect edits
- Cons: Some users are left out, even if they are just starting on SO and want to contribute.

**Minimum tag score or tag badge required for approving changes**

- Pros: Any user can propose a change, and users above the minimum tag score can approve it. This solves the con from above.
- Cons: Tags with not so many users will have proposed changes sitting in the queue for days, waiting for the few people who can to approve the changes.

**Minimum reputation required for approving changes**

- Pros: Tags with not so many users can get still get the changes approved. This solves the con from above.
- Cons: Those with high reputation but unfamiliar with the topic can still approve changes.

### My Proposal

Taking from "Minimum tag score or tag badge required for approving changes" above:

- Anyone can propose an edit. This allows users to contribute who may be experienced in the topic but haven't contributed on SO proper.
- At least one person with at least the bronze tag badge has to approve/reject the proposed change before it becomes final. This is to provide accuracy to the docs (slightly changed thanks to @4castle in the comments—see edit history for the previous revision).

As for preventing proposed changes from sitting in the review queue...

#### For New Proposals

- Change the criteria for a tag to be eligible on documentation from 500 questions to 25 people with at least the bronze tag badge. This prevents dead tags like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/zend-framework2/topics), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wso2/topics), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webstorm/topics). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) for the number of bronze tag badges that have been awarded for each tag.
- Out of the 5 people who commit to the proposal, one must have at least the bronze tag badge.

#### For Existing Tags

- For those that meet the criteria above, do nothing!
- For those that do not meet the criteria above:

  - If it is dead (no one is contributing or 1 person has a bunch of proposed edits that will never be approved), refer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328506/we-need-to-be-able-to-flag-problematic-documentation-tags).
  - Otherwise, I currently do not know of a solution (manually look to see if one or two of the reviewers have the bronze tag badge?).

<sub>Note: Anywhere I said "bronze tag badge" could be replaced with "25 tag score" or "50 tag score". The bronze tag badge is just a reasonable example that SO already implements and [records users who have it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze).</sub>

Comment: Or another option, require that at least one of the people approving have a bronze tag. I also feel that the bronze tag requirement could be reduced.

Comment: @4castle "one of the people approving have a bronze tag" I think that's what I said, let me know if I could make that clearer. As for the bronze tag requirement, that's just implemented on SO already, but I guess it could be changed to 25 or 50 tag score (instead of 100). SO already tracks awarded bronze tag badges also, so it would be easy to determine docs eligibility using bronze tag badges.

Comment: What I meant was, say it takes 3 people to approve an edit. Only 1 of those people need to be experienced in the tag (for verifying accuracy), the other 2 people would be for making sure stuff is in the right format. It seems most edits which are rejected don't even require knowledge of the topic in order to spot.

Comment: @4castle I see what you mean, that's actually a good idea. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Technically not bad. But there though are a bunch of tags which are important should be documented, but still have not a lot of bronze-badge holders. Take for example network-programming. A very important topic. But it doesn't have 25 bronze badge holders. [not by a large margin, but still]. You are essentially proposing to exclude important tags because there are not very much questions about it. The more specific a domain is, the less questions there are. But this doesn't make it any less important.

Comment: @bwoebi True, we could just remove the 25 bronze badge criteria (maybe make it 5 just for dead tag safety?) but keep the requirement of at least one person with at least a bronze badge to commit.

Comment: @bwoebi But then again, the bronze badge is just an already-implemented SO feature. It could be reduced to 25 or 50 tag score if needed.

Comment: Additionally, bronze badges are quite fast earned for large topics. Most people have their first bronze badge with around 2k rep. There are so many people in e.g. the PHP tag with bronze badges (over 3.2k)… I don't want to trust most of them. It mitigates part of the problem, but doesn't solve it really.

Comment: I just want to say, it has a strong bias towards large topics. The larger a topic is, the more questions there are, the faster you get to a bronze badge with little knowledge. It is quite not universally applicable. It either allows too much reviewers or not enough. 25 bronze badge holders of which 1 is active/interested in documentation is not enough. And 3.2k possible reviewers are far too much, then we could just as well allow anyone with 2k+ rep.

Comment: @bwoebi Yes, there are going to be problems with this, but there is currently no solution set in place, at least this is something.

Comment: @bwoebi There could even be some implementation to check the number of bronze badge holders, and if there is too many, use the silver badge holders instead. But something needs to be tried out first before more small refinements take place.

Comment: @tktsubota Thinking about it, one could perhaps allow e.g. the top 1000 people with at least a 20 score in a tag or having 400+ score in a tag to be able to always review. Everyone else can also review, but their votes are non-binding. Then, when they have reviewed a consecutive 30 times with a high success rate (say 28 times out of 30 they were right), their votes become binding. I just strongly dislike the idea of flat out disallowing people to review because they're not that long on the site or similar.

Comment: @bwoebi That might really work! It's slightly complex, but the best I've seen.

Comment: @bwoebi I love the idea. It takes both the top of the lesser-known tags (with a small minimum requirement) and the very top of the more popular tags (silver tag badge) to always review, while allowing others to get a chance by proving themselves.

Comment: @tktsubota feel free to propose that in a separate feature-request to be debated and voted upon, if you really like it. In a comment not that much people will see it ;o)

Comment: @bwoebi Sure, I'll get started on that.

Comment: "with at least the bronze tag badge" I won't be able to monitor the proposed changes anymore. A new iron badge could be introduced.

Comment: I like the idea of greater reviewing power with tag score, but I think it shouldn't be a hard-and-fast barrier, since that wouldn't apply well over all tags and would be rejected by the SO staff on principle (as shown on the feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329551/). We could require five votes to approve, but give bronze badgers a tag weight of three; silver four; and gold five. Then have a proposal fail when it reaches a net score of -3 or worse.

Comment: We want to be thoughtful before jumping to changes *too* quickly after seeing how things go, but FWIW I like the thinking here.  We're **extremely** reluctant to establish any restrictions that prevent (or significantly restrict) new users from contributing and getting involved, but SOME kind of validation on the approval side seems like a logical approach to look at.

Comment: Burninate as we do for SO tags?

Comment: I would say that if it is based on tag score, then it would really raise the entry barrier because the easier questions are already answered. There are only so many questions that can be answered.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328703/addressing-documentation-repgateapocalypse/328708#328708 cc @Jaydles

Comment: @bwoebi The [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329677/incorrect-information-in-documentation-the-solution) is up.

Comment: Hmm... about your proposal, or the similar ones you mentioned: Out of curiosity, if a user suggests an edit, and this edit is approved, would it be logical for it to increase their tag score by 1, for demonstrating knowledge of the subject?  If so, would this be limited to substantial edits, to prevent it from being abusedby making small edits to fix grammar/typoes/etc.?

Comment: @JustinTime I haven't really thought about that, but as of right now, with documentation going crazy and not everything sorted out yet (at all), that wouldn't be something I would do.

Comment: @JustinTime That's probably a bad idea because it would mess with Q&A privileges. I'd consider giving a "documentation" bronze badge for having many documentation contributions. It would need to have a purpose though

Comment: @tktsubota Hadn't thought of that, this definitely wouldn't be the best time for something like that.

Comment: @4castle Ah, okay.  Makes sense.  It might work if the Q&A and documentation sections had different reputation counters, but that doesn't appear to be planned.

Comment: The bronze badge isn't workable for me. What do you do for topics such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sitecore/topics) literally no one will be able to approve or reject edits.

Comment: I agree, it is getting extremely frustrating to DAILY, have to edit the same documentation page over and over again because people keep changing the code, or logic of the example, making the example incorrect or simply illogical.

Comment: I am unsure on the bronze / silver / gold badge requirement idea, because this may significantly limit the number of people that would be able to contribute.  Similar to how many of the people that "moderate" the site (ie. review queues, flag / editing bad posts, etc.) do not necessarily participate in Q&A as much as other people, we may see a similar thing with Documentation.  The people with big badges may not be interested in contributing to the docs.  I have an idea, why don't we just limit the daily rep cap to 150(ish) for documentation, instead of 200? problem solved.

Comment: @iliketocode The feature request has an alternative solution.

Answer (score 139):

I should preface this (somewhat negative, I'm afraid) post with a comment that I've felt uneasy with the Documentation proposal from the outset—though I've hitherto reserved judgment, hoping that my pessimism would ultimately prove unfounded and it would become the "Wikipedia" of technical knowledge.

Now seeing it in action, however, I am really very uncomfortable with it indeed.

My Q&A contributions to date have primarily been in [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), whose official [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/) I have always found to be very thorough whilst easy to navigate and comprehend.  I therefore approached StackOverflow's new [MySQL Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/) with some trepidation, fearing it would at best duplicate the official resource or at worst become a disorganised mess of poorly written tutorials that fail to address edge cases.

So far, what I see is closer to the latter than the former.  Granted, over time the quality of specific topics/examples should improve: but there's *so much* work to do, and relatively few contributors who write to a satisfactory level of quality, that I fear low quality contributions will (if not have already) become quite overwhelming—much [as is already the case with Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252506).  Even with sufficient high quality contributors, each tag's documentation would require dedicated curators to maintain consistency and organisation.

Indeed, we appear simply to have taken all of the issues that have been raised over quality on StackOverflow and embodied them in something that purports (or at least, strives) to be *even more* canonical.  This is disastrous.

**The only way that I can see this being (potentially) salvageable is to hugely restrict those who may contribute to Documentation.**  Unlike Wikipedia (which is generally only edited by people who have "reasonable" subject knowledge) I fear that many StackOverflow users—perhaps programmers in general—either *think* they understand their subject a lot better than they actually do, or often just post anyway about things *they know they don't fully understand* (perhaps in some attempt to win more magical unicorn points).  I certainly wouldn't pretend that I've never fallen into one, or both, of those categories myself.

I don't even think editing Documentation is a privilege that should be linked to SO reputation, which is ostensibly a measure of one's problem solving abilities—after all, good technical writing is a skill that does not necessarily bear much correlation to diagnostic skills.  I suspect it should perhaps be awarded more manually, based on the quality and detail of one's posts.

Apologies again for this (not very constructive?) rant—I just feel so much effort has already been (and is still to be) expended on this project, and I'm skeptical it's adding any value, that I think it urgently requires deeper thought before it's allowed to progress further.

I'm inclined to suggest that the public beta should be suspended until these problems are addressed.

Comment: I could not agree more. As much as I would love to encourage and reward people in, say, our tag of mysql, it has been rather awful. There needs to be some tying of tag rep to moderation (including deletes) in my opinion.

Comment: Also, I have about 5 times invited people who post there in that Docs section to join me in the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) room for consolidating efforts and getting some consistency. And reviewing and approving type of stuff. Only Rick James is there.

Comment: I totally agree that documentation does not have to do much with SO rating. SO rating is somewhat small indication of anything to be honest (a pity, that), because of the massive amount of users just sitting there and answering same simple/duplicated/easily googled questions. Technical writing skills, structuring material, choosing laconic examples - this is what important when writing documentation.

Comment: Very nice post. I see the problem of not enough high quality content, but I'm also worried about the missing structure of the content. It's just all thrown at you. Increasing the expert contributors ratio is one thing but having a better organization of the content is another very important point in my opinion.

Comment: I'll add my 2 cents: the name "Documentation" kind of implies a certain level of, well, documentation. I've contributed but, to be honest, between the layout of information and topics, the gamification of the information provided and the general mechanics of it all, documentation it is not. It might be more apt if it were instead named something like "Examples", at least then I have no preconceived notions that I can dive into the `C++` topic and start reading specific documentation about the language, syntax, semantics, specifications and/or library abilities..

Comment: If this is not meant to be actual documentation but just a blob of searchable, community-curated examples, then there are still two problems:
 - Why is it called Documentation?
 - How does this add anything that we don't already have with Stack Overflow?

Comment: Agreed. Documentations need to be accurate and correct, which is not everyone can do.

Comment: I agree, public beta should be suspended until these problems are resolved

Comment: This, a hundred times this. I won't name the tag but I have visited one and the documentation there is apparently random, poorly written, and just not very good as far as content is concerned. I think the people who are contributing are probably good, knowledgeable people who want to help others; but that isn't enough to write coherent and comprehensive documentation. What we really need is for people to organize teams for each tag and for those teams to define a process to produce documentation. Built-in support from the platform - like is done for voting for mods - would be invaluable.

Comment: I agree with this, plus more. One big problem is that a user will, naturally, focus on the way they do things, which, while not necessarily a bad way to do things may not be the only good way, and could lead to a misleading or restrictive view of a subject. As an example in my field, which is Delphi, a topic of interfaces focusses a lot on TInterfacedObject. Now while that user may always descend from TInterfacedObject, and that may give great benefits to his style of programming, that is not really what interfaces are all about, and that is certainly not the only way to use interfaces.

Comment: My main areas are HTML and CSS, and the SO Documentation in those areas is already falling heavily towards a muddle of non-documentation examples plus content plagiarized directly from Mozilla Developer Network, which until now has been the de facto "source" (nb I'm not an MDN editor so don't follow its internals, so don't know if they have trouble with original content vs. plagiarizing from W3). So that's one a problem. Then talking about examples: 1) SO already encourages examples in answers, and 2) how can we make sure examples aren't plagiarized from existing SO answers?

Comment: You want to throw out the baby with the bathwater. At least judging from what you wrote, you're not even trying to empathize with the common user who just wants to look at the documentation, you're looking at the whole thing from an incredibly narrow perspective and find that it's not perfect in some way so it should be suspended. This is what people complain about when they say this site has an issue with elitism. Might as well turn off the internet and burn all books by the same logic.

Comment: I agree with this. Now that I see what it has turned out to be, it's even worse than I feared and [warned about](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/305786#comment246700_305786). It's a worthless mess. This would be an easy opportunity to grind more reputation in a couple of hours than I've gathered with *relevant* contributions in the past 5 years, but I don't even want to contribute to this mistake. Keep documentation where it belongs, in the structure it makes most sense in, instead of poorly duplicating it here.

Comment: another totally agree comment. I think SE tries to spread itself too thin, rather then sticking to what it does well, question and answer sites.

Answer (score 62):

This is pretty great. A tight feedback loop and lots of transparency is always good to see.

I think that the next most important topic after the massive queues is the [fairly illogical ordering of the topics on documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329003/documentation-doesnt-look-good-right-now). I can't pick a topic and start learning it, which I think is a great measure of success for the documentation project.

Comment: Solve with some nice search function.

Comment: @tbodt: You seem to miss the point - if you don't know which one you should start from, how would you search?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, I missed the point. I still think search should be improved, though.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a page that redirects to a random article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) It wouldn't be hard to implement something similar, I think.

Comment: @dorukayhan You're missing the point. Its not for me to be able to actually pick a random topic. Its for me to be able to choose anything I want and learn it easily. I can't do that now with the current system because there is no organization

Comment: It's a cookbook.  You don't browse it to learn; you arrive from Google and copy the "example" you want.

Comment: "I can't pick a topic and start learning it" Well, no. If you want to learn something properly you need a properly-structured tutorial that you can work through in a linear fashion. Most programming docs do not have that linear structure and so are not a great way to learn a language or framework. Sure, you may need to refer to the docs while working through a tutorial, to get extra details, or to clarify technical issues.

Comment: (cont) Hopefully, (once the "teething problems" have been sorted out) the explanations and examples in SO Documentation will act as a useful supplement to the existing docs, but they aren't intended to be a tutorial. OTOH, I guess it would be _possible_ to have a list of "Suggested Reading Order" information for significant topics, but AFAIK that sort of thing is not in the current scope. And while such a thing _may_ be helpful when _revising_ a topic, I don't think it's a good substitute for a properly-structured tutorial when you're trying to learn the material initially.

Comment: @PM2Ring this isn't really true.... Java, angular,, mongo, CPP, .net, etc all have learning guides in their docs. We're looking to make the best product out there and I think that includes some structure

Comment: Ok. I mostly do Python these days (although I have learned many languages over the decades). The official Python tutorial is excellent (for those who already know how to program), and it _is_ packaged with the rest of the official Python docs, but I tend to think of the tutorial as separate from the Language Reference and Library Reference portions of the docs.

Comment: (cont)  I see SO Docs as corresponding more to Language and Library docs; I don't see how tutorial material would work well with this format: it's hard to write that sort of material coherently unless it's done by a single author or a small team that know each other well. Crowd-sourcing it sounds like a recipe for an inconsistent mess.

Comment: What would be great eventually is to be able to create learning guides that pull good examples from documentation and are linear-based for those just learning a language.

Comment: @David We shouldn't be aiming to duplicate e.g. the official Java Tutorials.  That would be a tremendous waste of effort.  I understand why you'd think that, with the feature being named _Documentation_ and all, but it's not intended to replace, well, actual documentation.  The example-first/only workflow and tooling clearly points to being a cookbook, and at least that's something that may not exist elsewhere.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I would like to do both, coming from a search engine with a specific problem but also browsing and learning. So a better ordering of the topics would be highly appreciated. And also for contributing it would be nice to actually get an overview about existing topics more easily.

Answer (score 53):

> The basic model (rep for example upvotes, approved changes, and
>   upvoting answers citing docs) doesn’t seem terribly broken

It ***is*** terribly broken. There are plenty of examples about why it's ***completely*** broken. It's not just a matter of threshold configuration or whatever you call it.

- [Remove or Overhaul Reputation in Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329528/remove-or-overhaul-reputation-in-documentation)
- [Documentation shares the work: make the rewards shared, not multiplicative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329506/documentation-shares-the-work-make-the-rewards-shared-not-multiplicative)
- [How much reputation is given per documentation post per day - convert to community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/how-much-reputation-is-given-per-documentation-post-per-day-convert-to-communi)
- [Can we please introduce more reputation limits for examples on Documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation)
- Etc.

> Expect more reputation tweaks in the coming weeks

I would expect a ***complete reworking***, not just *some tweaks*.

---

From the comments:

> That quote is missing the context of "but the limits (like who gets
>   rep for examples, and how much) definitely need work."

It's not a matter of limits, or thresholds. It's basically how the rep model is designed. See the links I provided.

Comment: My comment no longer makes sense in the context of this answers so I'm removing it. The sentiment to it was changes are happening, but it's going to take time, I don't expect it to look the same in a few months as it did at launch.

Comment: I agree changes need to be made. It's been four days since launch, changes are going to continually happen until we get it right. There's no way this community will allow anything less than fair distribution of rep (as we shouldn't.) We had more testing in 24 hours on SO than the entire six months of private beta.

Comment: @ken2k: The 1 to 1k user thing in hours was fixed when Docs.SO rep was properly capped. That was a bug, and it was fixed within 24 hours of Docs going live. Now, they still get 200 rep per day, so it only takes them 5 days to hit 1k.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks for pointing this out, it's now indeed 1k every 5 days.

Answer (score 44):

*Re-posting from [Remove or Overhaul Reputation in Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329528/remove-or-overhaul-reputation-in-documentation)*

---

I think that the cheap reputation influx from Documentation may actually have a tangible adverse effect on the participation in the Q&A section of the site, since it disincentivizes users from investing time into actually helping people, when right next door they can make ridiculous amounts of reputation by changing "do not" to "don't", making a Hello World program du jour have proper brackets placement for the language in question and copy-pasting text and source code verbatim from corresponding technology's own documentation.

Call me a rep whore, overcome with green mouth-foaming envy (and you would be absolutely right in this assessment), but I feel utterly disheartened by Docs giving out thousands of rep to users in several days for contributions as valuable and expertise-demanding as I've just described, when achieving comparable results on the Q&A would take months of actual effort and even, occasionally, a shred of expertise.

For me personally this doesn't (yet) kill the motivation to invest time and effort into answering questions on the main site, but it does diminish it quite a bit. And I'm not the only user who feels this way:

- [comment by Ares](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329506/documentation-shares-the-work-make-the-rewards-shared-not-multiplicative#comment372935_329506)
- [comment by Gert Arnold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/how-much-reputation-is-given-per-documentation-post-per-day-convert-to-communi/329513#comment373041_329513)
- ...many other comments of similar nature

Now, I realise that there are low-hanging fruit questions asked every day, which require no effort either. Indeed, my own most upvoted answer is the one stating that `private` instance variables are accessible from other instances of the same class (some revelatory stuff!). However, most of them get promptly closed as duplicates, since there are only so many basic concepts to clear up in each topic, while others get a few smug comments, a few obvious answers from desperate users with below 1K rep (such as myself) and, crucially, **get washed down the ever-flowing stream of history**, never to be seen by a potential upvoter again, instead of being nailed to the top of the entire site section, getting constant drops of basically free reputation forever.

So, in short, I don't think that psychological effects of having Docs reputation contribute to the same pool as the Q&A have been great so far and I don't see the situation being improved just by "tweaking" the existing system.
I think Documentation should be purely altruistic, [for its own quality's sake](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329003/documentation-doesnt-look-good-right-now), or at least that rep pools should be separated.

Comment: I suppose this is somewhat verifiable. Could track answer upvotes and answers in general and see if the public beta of Docs had an impact.

Comment: I concur. If anything, please award a flat amount of rep per edit. (i.e. +5 max). I've edited over a 1000 posts on SO and the most I've gotten was +2 rep per post for only the first hundred or so posts I edited. Conversely, you can just ride the rep train by making trivial edits to documentation and earn massive reputation with almost 0 effort.

Comment: I definitely agree that the high rep from documentation is a problem. On new q/a sites, it is my understanding that initially reputation is fairly easy to get. Although rep probably needs to be harder to get in documentation, I think rep still needs to be easier to get than on so q/a. I suggest separating rep on the two is and will remain essential. Perhaps cross-site rep should be considered for privileges, though.

Answer (score 33):

A lot of contributions I'm seeing are more like, "here's some example code with no explanation of how it works". That's not documentation, that's not even acceptable in an SO answer. When I click on "Proposed changes > Reject", one of the reasons should be "needs more details" or I should be able to link to an existing, more complete entry (if one exists), as is possible with the "dismiss topic" link.

Comment: We should either reject those examples without context in the review process or flag them later for improvement or downvote them. This is a serious problem, but one that is solvable by the current means, I guess.

Comment: Or one could add a subsequent edit with the required additional information?

Comment: This and: that wouldn't be an acceptable SO answer, but many of the best SO answers include examples. So not only is Documentation heading towards really being Examples, but we _already have_ an existing, stable, well-curated body of examples in the form of SO itself. I hate to say it, but at the time of this writing Documentation is heading towards being a sort of SO knockoff but not as well done.

Answer (score 15):

I think it should also be possible to move topics from one tag to another, if they are requested/created in the wrong tag.

Comment: Possibly. I'd like to wait for some more data here because, if nothing else, the UI is hard to work out in a way that makes any sort of sense... and I sort of expect topics to be migratable between tags, but individual examples are perhaps too granular?

Comment: I meant topics... :|

Comment: @AdamLear You need a better way of correcting tags than having to submit them to a moderator, which is all I could find at present.

Comment: Regarding moving topics, your deletion and recreation of a very popular topic has led to several complaints on Meta that you may want to respond to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329570/there-should-be-a-way-to-refine-a-deleted-example-for-contributors http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329596/examples-deleted-from-documentation http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329630/highly-voted-topic-deleted-and-recreated

Comment: @EJP Did you see the bit about merges and aliases in the question here? That's where we're gonna start. It's a rather destructive operation, so it'll be employee-only to begin with. We'll possibly see about making it available more broadly, but there's of course no ETA at the moment.

Comment: @AdamLear I guess a good approach for the UI for such thing would be using the flagging mechanism. You flag for migration, give a reason, the issue is reviewed and if agreed upon the migration is performed. Possibly both, reviewers from the originating tag as well as the target tag have to agree.

Answer (score 14):

The biggest problem I see so far with documentation is plagiarism. People are copying and pasting from official documentation without even adding any commentary or usage guidelines, which adds no value and is of questionable legality. Sometimes they'll add a link back, but when 99% of the content on your page is copied from an external source I don't think you can claim fair use.

Answer (score 12):

One thing that I faced that might need attention: **Creating a topic is too easy.** Quite a few times it would suffice to have an example under a - mostly already existing - topic...

For example: [Creating an executable jar file in Windows without using IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52585)

**Could we restrict topic creation?**

- some kind of minimal rep?
- approval required by multiple people (with enough reps)?

This could help in shaping the content, and keep it organized...

Answer (score 11):

About the tag part, I don't exactly understand how they work.

See this basic example: Hello World... There is [one topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/14/introduction-to-net/28/hello-world-in-c-sharp#t=201607260719553963719) in the .NET tag that gives examples on how to do it in several languages: C#, F#, VB.NET and C++/CLI.

Then there is [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/352/hello-world#t=201607260724269196663), in th VB.NET Language tag, that explains how to build Hello World in VB.NET.

There is no link from one topic to another, but clearly there should be, as it is the exact same thing they are trying to achieve...

I think that there should be a difference between an actual programming language and a library that can be used on many languages.

- An actual language, you should be able to write example out of it, and if your topic is linked to a library, you can tag this library (like the .NET Framework)
- A library, you should not be able to write an example only with this library tag (no one can code only in the .NET, you still need a language...). A library is tagged in the examples. And then is viewable in the all topics but specifying somehow that this is not a language...)

I don't know if this looks interesting to anyone, but I felt like sharing this, as it might be a start for writing a documentation library based on language examples...

Comment: Similar issues arise with frameworks available on both iOS and OS X, which are used in Objectvie-C and Swift languages. There is not a clear way to categorize topics and we can expect duplicates.

Comment: @Tricertops That's what I'm afraid of... Without a good categorization and organisation, this whole documentation project might become unusable because unclear...

Comment: Good multi-language support would fix this problem. ...along with a massive clean up effort.

Comment: Having more than a single tag per topic would be nice. Having subtags would be nice. ... As in the Q&A part of SO.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for the update! Weekly updates are a great idea, especially in the beginning now.

Now a little feedback on your planned improvements:

#### The review queue for proposed changes

I perhaps would not put everything in this queue. The tags where there are enough contributors, especially with enough people having the necessary domain knowledge, work fine currently.

It is easy, as someone with not so much domain knowledge about a specific topic to accidentally approve something factually wrong. Currently, I'm regularly checking through the list of already approved proposals to spot whether the approvals were fine... They really aren't always. It is already bad enough [I've had everyday seen 1-2 factually wrong proposals which got approved]. I cannot imagine a general purpose review queue improving this situation. See also: [What can we do about robo-reviewing on documentation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329572/what-can-we-do-about-robo-reviewing-on-documentation)

Thus, I'd suggest that the review queue to be used mainly for low-frequency tags where the time until approval is exceeding 12-24 hours. As it is really valuable to have the proposals reviewed by domain experts. Just in case there are none, it must go through the generic queue.

Alternatively, you can have the queue *by default* only for low-frequency tags and allow people to opt-in for other tags (if they are knowledgeable there).

Perhaps, there are better ways than I proposed, the main point is:

- **Reviewing well-frequented tags** *[where enough reviewers exist]* **should *definitely not* be a low hanging fruit.**

Apart from that: Thanks for including "Edit & Approve". Editing should though *not* immediately be approved, else it is an easy way to game the system and introduce yourself factually wrong information without further review. (see also [Improving requested edits in Stack Overflow Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328455/improving-requested-edits-in-stack-overflow-documentation))

#### Tag merges

They are nice to have, and I can just think of a few issues in case a tag needs to be split up (some topics belong more to one tag, and some more to the other one), or only parts of a tag needing to be split out. This should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Been wondering about review queue myself. It's relatively easy to review Q/A in majority of cases without knowing anything about a language , it's usually about structure of the post itself. Docs examples are the opposite

Comment: Exactly my point. And thus it should be tried to favor those people for reviewing who can really verify it instead of the opposite [=> general public of people with 2k+ rep [or whatever the limits will be on that queue]].

Comment: However...click on image and note there is a tag filter showing

Comment: @charlietfl that's a filter like the normal suggested edits queue also has one. The filter is off by default, I suppose, though.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I understand the overall reason for the Documentation site; I mean, it seems very structured and formatted as if there is only one way to write documentation.

I understand the need for more examples, but a lot of good documentation is prose.

Some specific observations:

- Why, after I click on the Documentation<sup>Beta</sup> link, and then click on Questions, does it take me to the recents tab? I thought it would take me the Home tab.

  - From the StackOverflow home page, click on Documentation<sup>Beta</sup>
  - Next, Click on Questions (on the top of the site, to the left of the Jobs link).
  - Result: You are taken to the main StackOverflow page, with the "recents" tab selected.
  - Expected: You are taken to the main StackOverflow page, with the "home" tab selected.
- Is there a way to allow monospaced text, without the grey background? This is useful in tables when defining parameter values.
- Speaking of the Parameters section, why can't I write normal text in it? Sometimes, a parameter requires a footnote or other explanation that is out of place in a table. However, when I tried to do this it gave me a "can only contain two column table" error. Why this specific restriction?

Comment: It may help if you think of Docs as a cookbook, not a tutorial or reference manual; it doesn't have to replace the latter.  The devs have said they strongly considered naming the feature Examples, and the private beta help said ideal examples were copy-pasteable (though they've since backed away from that).  To put it another way, they committed to doing one thing (examples) and doing it well.  See also [Jon Ericson's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330003/3614835), which is the best quasi-official explanation so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "click on Home"? Or "Home tab". I might be missing something here, but I don't see those terms anywhere on the page?

Comment: Sorry Adam, it was a pre-coffee posting. I mean the `Questions` link.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom "It may help if you think of Docs as a cookbook, not a tutorial or reference manual": herein lies the main problem with SO Docs. *no one* knows what it's supposed to be. You think it's cookbooks. Others think it's reference material. Yet some others think that "Documentation" implies, well, actual documentation. So what it it, really?

Comment: "good documentation is prose". Quite. I think a better name for now would be Spaghetti: as in that-which-one-throws-at-the-wall-to-see-if-it-sticks.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the problem of too many examples per topic - I think this comes back to the structure of documentation and the two ways that this allows it to be used.

---

- As a book - i.e. a topic is a chapter.

Thus a "String Manipulation" topic will have lots of examples for how to perform the multiple ways of manipulating strings (creation, concatenation, copying, searching, splitting, length-counting, character and sub-string replacement, etc) in different contexts and use-cases (At definition time, statically allocated strings, dynamically allocated strings, best practice vs low-memory environments, etc).

- As a reference - i.e. a topic is based around one single facet.

Thus a single topic could be "String Concatenation" and then provide documentation for the basic string concatenation function of a language covering only the common, basic, use-cases. Other string concatenation functions or use cases would be covered in more specifically named topics.

---

Here is the issue. Documentation is *structured* for the latter (a topic name, a small number examples, a syntax section [itself implying application to a single code operation], and the remarks section being towards the end rather than the start), but is *used* for the former (titles over concepts rather than specifics, remarks section used as topic descriptions rather than short, well, remarks, syntax sections being over-run with attempts to document syntax for all the items documented within a chapter topic).

Personally I feel that the current usage we see is actually producing a more helpful Documentation than a reference style. But it does not suit the current structure. The resulting conclusion being that the structure of Documentation needs rejigging to better match the reality of its use.