# There should be a way to refine a deleted example for contributors

Tags: discussion, documentation

Today, when I woke and visited SO as usual, but I just found the [sorting arrays example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/423) in Java have been deleted by someone.

I'm really surprised for:

1. I think it's very good example, and I think there is no reason to delete such a good example.
2. I can't find who and why(who submit the proposed change and who approved that) to delete that.
3. I found no way to refine that example if it's deleted. When a example is deleted, I think every contributor of that example should get a notification for refining that example (just like a closed question can be refined, then vote for reopen).

So, I suggest when a example is deleted:

1. Notice all of contributor the reason of deletion
2. Let contributor to refine and re-submit that example for review

PS:

I'm still interested in the reason of deleting [sorting arrays example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/423)...

Comment: And particularly there's no way to view these deleted examples... they are just 404 links, even for 10k+ or mods.

Comment: Perhaps it was copied from another site?

Comment: @bwoebi, actually you can view the edit: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52704
the example just got deleted and recreated, both was requested by this user: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1455016/tbodt) and approved by this user: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/1896169/justin).
I think it should be possible to protect example, or only let mods remove examples that have so many upvotes

Comment: @bpoiss And how do you find that particular edit? On page five of the backlog of the proposals of that tag? There should be a way to directly see previous examples on a page... As well as previous topics.

Comment: @bwoebi yeah you are right, I hope there will be an improvement soon

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah wtf, I just lost 150 rep because he moved it... There goes all my contributions to that example.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Should moderator undo that change? I think it really causes harm to those contributors...

Comment: I think a moderator will be the only one able to put the Sorting Arrays example back into the Arrays topic without also rolling back every other example in the Arrays topic 7+ hours.

Comment: @JonnyHenly My intention was not to take all the rep for myself, it was to take an example that was composed of about six examples and move it to a new topic. In the process, though, the votes got lost, even though I used the "move example" button. That's probably because I ended up deleting the original example in my draft and moving all the info to new ones. If the change was reverted, I'd be willing to redo it and leave the votes on the original example.

Comment: I apologize @tbodt, I wasn't trying to throw you under the bus. I was shocked that a single user can delete an example that has been edited by 56 different users and upvoted 123 times, just by the approval of **one** other user, and the  user that moves the example becomes the original author. I shouldn't have used wordage that implied that you were gaming the system. I could have worded that better.

Comment: It is definitely time for moderators to step in, and for SO to change the way how the examples can be deleted. If it doesn't, some crazy user in the future can revert all the hard work contributed by numerous authors.

Comment: Looks like these links are working again now, and show where the example was moved to.

Answer (score 5):

You can still find the deleted *example*, you just have to go about it in a roundabout way.

If you go to your profile and click the `Activity` tab then go to the `documentation` tab, you'll see `edited example    Sorting Arrays`.

[image]

---

If you follow the [Sorting Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/423/sorting-arrays#t=20160725222824087) link it will take you to the [Java Language | Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays) topic with a blueish gray message box stating *"Linked example has been deleted; [view prior to deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/423/sorting-arrays?asOf=20160725222824087)."*

[image]

---

Following the link in that message box will show you the `Sorting Arrays` example prior to deletion.

[image]

And if you scroll all the way up you'll see another message box that says *"You're viewing this topic as it existed [...]."* with a blue outlined button whose text states *"Create draft rolling back to this version"*

[image]

I don't know what clicking that button will do, but I suspect that it will create a draft to roll back the entire `Arrays` topic.

Comment: That's still very bad user-experience. Does it work on whole topics too? … Also, what's the way to go if you don't remember who contributed to a topic?

Comment: @bwoebi Agreed. I'm actually not sure, probably not though. I was using this url, `stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/53202`, and decreasing the last number by 1, trying to find the proposed change that deleted the Sorting Arrays example. But once I reached `53100` I realized the insanity to that approach and then stumbled upon this *solution*. A lot of the url's went to actual proposals but some went to the 404 redirect, I think those proposed changes deleted entire topics.

Comment: @bwoebi I think you're SOL if you don't remember who contributed to a topic. It's way too easy to delete massive amounts of information from DOCs. Especially with robo-reviewers like the one you found earlier.

Comment: I clicked that `rolling back` button, and I saw the content of `sorting arrays` example. But if I submit that example again, I think it will be a new example with only 1 contributor(me) and zero vote. It's really unfair to submit it as a new example for guys who contributed that example before...

Comment: @Sayakiss I know what you mean, and if that occurs you might get accused of trying to game the system. Part of me thinks it will roll back every example in the Arrays topic to the point of when Sorting Arrays got deleted, another part thinks it will just add it back to the Arrays topic. Only one way to find out though.