# Highly-voted topic deleted and recreated

Tags: discussion, bug, documentation

It seems like the [Sorting Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/e/423) topic was deleted on Monday.

The topic can still be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/423/sorting-arrays#t=20160725222824087), which is accessed by `view prior to deletion` feature.

> Proposed Change for removing the example:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52704
>
> [image: Image 1]

Then, the topic was recreated.

> Proposed Change for adding the example:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/52702
>
> [image: Image 2]

---

Because of this move, the example now only has 1 contributor, which was in fact contributed by 53 users and upvoted 123 times in the original example.

---

Even though, the user wanted to move the example to a different topic, I think Documentation should have measures in place to prevent this.

This is also the downsides of having only 1 user to approve an edit, whereas 3 users are required to approve an edit in Q & A. Thus, I still believe that **at least** 2 users are required to approve or reject a proposed change to be fair to others.

Comment: Yeh, and now you need to educate people to also reject it if not done via example moving tool...

Comment: @bwoebi Yup, but I think Docs should require at least 2 users for approval or rejection, 1 is too less

Comment: Yeah, I fully agree, but this is still only tangentially related. The eduction is more important. [for this specific issue]

Comment: @bwoebi and luweiqi, deletion requires two users anyway [Who can delete a documentation example?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328816)

Comment: @Braiam But it seems like in this case, one user approved the deletion

Comment: @Braiam it only takes two votes to delete the whole topic. Only one if its one example

Comment: Even if it required 2 approvals, with current rep system the incentive would be there for 2 colleagues to do this maliciously. Not saying that's what happened but the opportunity exists

Comment: Two other complaints about this same deletion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329596/examples-deleted-from-documentation http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329570/there-should-be-a-way-to-refine-a-deleted-example-for-contributors

Comment: "This is also the downsides of having only 1 user to approve an edit, whereas 3 users are required to approve an edit." I think there might be a wording mistake in this sentence. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: @BrianHowell Oops, I meant "whereas 3 users are required to approve an edit **in Q & A**", thanks for pointing out! :-)