# How can a peer-review let this happen?

Tags: support, review-audits, documentation-proposals

Just look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108415?filter-tags=python) in a "Documentation Proposed Changes". How can a peer-review approve such changes?

I also went to the profile of this user and saw that he gained around 80 reputation in 2 days, with half of it was similar spam, such as changing the title to uppercase or adding a word or space and so on. And the strange thing is all were approved.

Is this a flaw in system or is this legal?

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the side-by-side markdown view, you can see he added comments in various code blocks:

[image]

If the reviewers were in this mode, they might have thought he was adding some more information about the samples without realising the comments arn't rendered in the actual documentation. Not excusing the behaviour of not fully evaluating an edit, but it could be a reason.

Also, it appears like all of the edits that user has done are for their own posts, for which they don't need approval.

Comment: I dont think so. The user had only 100 rep before few days how can these originally be his own posts? Also check this link the last 10 edits he did are all spam and approved. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2806499/simplans?tab=reputation

Comment: @WaqasBukhary ah, I was looking at his post revisions, not documentation. I wouldn't necessarily call capitalisation changes "spam", but they should almost certainly be coupled with something of more substance rather than a word or two. There is one or two edits with reasonable changes, so maybe just over-zealous editing?

Comment: So the question is this acceptable in stack-overflow? Is this legal? Should others also start doing this to gain quick rep?

Comment: @WaqasBukhary this seems like an issue the Documentation review queues been having since it was launched: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329572/what-can-we-do-about-robo-reviewing-on-documentation?rq=1

Comment: @WaqasBukhary It's surely legal, since there is no law against adding HTML comments to an open website... Also note: *spam* is related to **advertising**. While the edits are *useless*, *irrelevant*, and *inapproriate* they are not *spam*, since they do not introduce any advertising. Keep this in mind especially when flagging, otherwise your flags will be declined.

Comment: The specific edit was also rolled back shortly after it was approved: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108447