# Let's organize the SQL documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

[Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) has been in public beta for about a week, and [some users have pointed out a few issues with the SQL docs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329575/chaos-building-in-sql-section-of-documentation), so before things get too unwieldy let's address some of the issues. I mentioned in  [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329575/chaos-building-in-sql-section-of-documentation#comment373375_329575) earlier this week and have been thinking about ways to fix them before they get too out of control.

---

### Problem

The basic problem is that the [SQL docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql) are overly broad and are becoming a catch-all for every platform.

Currently, there are many examples which are specific to a single database ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/747/common-table-expressions/5603/oracle-connect-by-in-sql-server-syntax#t=201607291522447282764), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/747/common-table-expressions/10828/recursively-generate-dates-extended-to-include-team-rostering-as-example#t=201607291522447282764)) and they won’t work on all platforms.

Having these mixed in the SQL docs could be incredibly confusing for a user wanting to learn SQL and the example won't work on their database due to syntax differences. Even the [sample tables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/280/example-databases-and-tables#t=201607291647036599692) will only work on MySQL.

**This is definitely a problem that we need to fix.**

### Possible Solutions

I have several ideas to fix some of the issues, but before <strike>I</strike> we take a machete to it, we need to have a discussion about it.

###Solution 1: Change the Name or Not

1. Change the name to ANSI SQL, which are the standards that **most** database platforms are based on. Then create an alias for [ansi-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansi-sql) which will point to the SQL docs; by creating the alias it will prevent ANSI-SQL docs from being created separately.
2. Leave the name SQL Docs, but edit the [overview topic - SQL versions and database engines](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/184/sql-versions-and-database-engines#t=201607291700292115149) make it clear these docs are for ANSI SQL only.
3. Do both, change the name and update the overview.

**Solution 2: Limit the scope of the SQL Docs to ANSI Standards**

The SQL docs should contain stuff that works on all platforms, i.e. the basics - SELECT, JOIN, UPDATE, most aggregate functions.  If we limit the SQL docs to ANSI standard SQL, then any topics or examples that have specific syntax in a database would go directly into the docs for that platform.

This would also mean that the [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/184/sql-versions-and-database-engines#t=20160729193800403571&a=versions) would be limited to databases that follow the ANSI SQL standards.

By making this change, the [cross apply, outer apply](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/2516/cross-apply-outer-apply#t=201607291728340374453) example should not be in the SQL docs but in the docs for each platform because this is only available in SQL Server and Oracle, not all platforms.

**Keep in mind, we can always cross-link docs!**

The current SQL docs have [some great examples in the SELECT topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/222/select#t=201607291739530004532), and there is a similar [topic for SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/67105), but instead of posting identical examples, the SQL Server version would contain any subtle differences it might have for SELECTing, with a link back to the SQL docs.

Fixing the existing topics would involve, if you see something in the SQL Docs that doesn't belong there, propose the topic in the correct tag, create an example in the right tag, and let's get rid of the duplicate in the SQL Docs.

**Solution 3:**

Get rid of the SQL tag docs all together, and only have documentation for each database platform.  This would prevent platform specific syntax from being placed in the wrong tag, but possibly would result in more identical work being placed across the multiple tags. *The caveat here is I'm not sure the feasibility of this at this point, but wanted to throw it out for discussion.*

---

### Keeping Docs Organized

Earlier this week, [we got the ability to add aliases](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328653/documentation-should-actively-reject-pledge-to-versioned-tags/329860#329860) between tags for documentation.  This means that we can point tags to a master version.

For example, [sql-server-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008), [sql-server-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2005), etc now point to the [SQL Server docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics), this will prevent docs for different versions from being created.  If a topic is version specific, then you can apply versioning to an example.

We didn't automatically add tag aliases because undoing that process is a giant pain, so if you see something that needs to be aliased to a master tag, then ask on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and we'll clean it up.

There are a few that I think we can still do, but I'd like some feedback first.  Some suggested aliases:

- [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) as master with an alias of [oracle10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle10g), [oracle12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle12c), maybe others like [plsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plsql)
- [sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) as master with an alias to [sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3)
- [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) as master with alias of [t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/t-sql)

### Pitch in and Help

Let's work together to get these docs in order. If you have other suggestions on how to organize these docs, then leave feedback here so the community can decide how best to proceed.

Finally, I've created [SQL Docs chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118361/sql-and-database-product-docs) for users to discuss how best to work through some of these issues.  Join us and help create and clean the SQL docs.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this @bluefeet - not forgetting your roots :)

Comment: @Phil Never!! I'll always love sql!

Comment: Sadly, the problems you point out aren't unique to the SQL docs.

Comment: Wasn't there a plan to allow examples in multiple languages, with some ability to select the language? Something like that could also be used to give examples in multiple SQL dialects at the same time

Comment: Good thoughts. It is frustrating to have near-duplicate information in, for instance, the "Oracle Database" section as the "SQL" section. I would support the option to rename to ANSI SQL and restrict to those standards, although I like what @MadScientist noted about adding examples in multiple languages.

Answer (score 11):

Even if it's infeasible, my vote is to get rid of the generic SQL tag altogether.

Why?

- There are more specific DBMS tags available.
- When looking at Documentation, the likelihood that someone is going to solely look for ANSI-based documentation as opposed to specific vendor documentation is slim.
- This increases the likelihood that fragmentation of platform-specific knowledge will occur, if an example belongs with both Oracle in an ANSI context and Oracle in a proprietary context.

You raise a very good point about documentation becoming split up among the common parts of every DBMS, but I'm speaking from my perspective here:  if I were to look at Documentation for information about how to perform a subquery in SQL Server, I don't think I'd much care for the ANSI or "generic" approach; I'd rather one that worked explicitly with SQL Server.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate here, try to think about it from a new user perspective trying to learn SQL - will they know to look at a specific platform or will they look for SQL docs?  This is part of the hesitation with get rid of SQL docs.  We have to think also how new people to SQL will look for stuff.

Comment: @bluefeet:  Interesting point; would a new user be looking at documentation for a technology that they don't know yet, or would they be learning the documentation through more official channels and looking to Documentation to help with a more specific aspect?  I suppose I envisioned Documentation being aimed at a more expert demographic; that is, devs that have seen a winter or two in this technology.  Newcomers to the technology...dunno.  I'm not sure if Documentation should bridge this gap.

Comment: That's tough to say but I'm trying to think big picture, we wouldn't want to make the docs difficult to maneuver for someone new to the SQL language. I'm not sure what the best answer is, we just need to consider it so we don't drive away possible users of it. You know?

Comment: And yet, 90% of the content between different SQL databases will be the same, since they support most of the same operations that work in mostly the same way.

Comment: However @NicolBolas on many of the platforms the syntax is could be slightly different which is part of the problem.

Comment: @bluefeet: Yes, each platform has its "peculiarities". But there is a rather substantial common subset of queries that works regardless of the backend. It's not good to duplicate effort in this regard.

Comment: @bluefeet:  I'm not opposed to making it friendly to navigate for the unfamiliar, but perhaps this is a question of scope.  Who are we trying to target:  developers who use the official docs but need a bit more insight into something off the beaten path, or developers who want to learn the technology but don't know where to start?  I feel like we'd want to define that before we make strong moves on revising/fixing things, since one kind of "fix" may introduce other problems depending on our goal.

Comment: @Makoto Docs overall is still very new, but right now we believe this will serve a developer who lands on a topic and they want to learn how to use it better. It's more for the user who is new to a concept with a technology and wants to see examples of how to proceed. This version of docs is not for a developer who is trying to follow a track to learn something.

Comment: Interesting, almost opposite to my initial feelings. I tend to think `sql` and then a drill-down to a platform specific variation if necessary. For example, `COALESCE` before Oracle specific `NVL`. My preference would be to try coding to the more generic `sql` versions all else being the same.

Answer (score 6):

#### Rename to ANSI SQL and change the overview

From personal experience, learning "SQL" in the broader sense (i.e., without targeting a specific DBMS) boils down to learning broad concepts, rather than actual executable code.

Topics like CRUD operations and database objects would fit there, but not more specific topics like the intricacies of `SELECT`, `INSERT INTO`, etc. as these are platform/DBMS specific.

I think making the SQL topic specific to ANSI SQL standards would be preferable in that regards, but at the expense of most examples being prose rather than code.

Comment: This. There's just too many examples that should be found in a common ANSI that would become dispersed throughout the non-standard extensions if we required things to go that way. I'd rather have one place explaining a JOIN than the same thing in 5 different ways, in 5 different doc categories.

Answer (score 5):

Although this question only asks about SQL, I think that the same concept applies to other tags, including [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)'s docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics). (There's actually no one standard for regexes.)

With both regex and SQL it is often easier to find the exact code you want...but in the wrong dialect. Little in the way of existing documentation covers this, so I feel we can step up and fill the void.

My approach towards regex has been to find and highlight the differences between different flavors. For example, the fact that `[\d]` may mean "match a digit" in some flavors or it may mean "match `d` or `\`" in others.

So far, one of the best examples of this I have is [my Example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/4524/escaping/15849/delimiters#t=201607292035075123613) about regex escaping and delimiters. I start out with a vague "many languages" and a generalized description, then I delve into the specifics for each language. (It's not comprehensive at this point, of course.)

---

Essentially, you can use these "umbrella tags" as bridges between the different flavors. This may be helpful to many beginners, and I feel that it will also be helpful to those who know one version well, but want to expand to similar technologies.

Comment: "With both regex and SQL it is often easier to find the exact code you want...but in the wrong dialect." This can be incredibly frustrating. It would be hard to coordinate, but it would be nice if the same examples could be shown for each dialect. There would have to be some way of linking examples with the exact same implementation in multiple dialects, though; copy-pasting just wouldn't cut it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot You may be interested in my contributions to the regex docs then. I've only just started putting things together, but [delimiters](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/4524/escaping/15849/delimiters#t=201607292030307227306) is the best example so far of what I want to accomplish.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot isn't that what http://use-the-index-luke.com/ was fixing?

Comment: What I've seen of your contributions in regex so far look really good in terms of trying to signify what works with what. Really, it's what versioning was for in the first place I believe. If others do that with other "umbrella tags" then I think that's a fair solution. (This is totally not a roundabout way of complimenting your regex doc contributions, who told you that?)

Comment: @Braiam I had never heard of it, but yeah, looks like the same principle. Since Docs.SO is actually Examples.SO, there wouldn't be nearly as much explanatory text, though. I'm imagining a "Select the first 10 rows" example in each of the MySQL, PostgreSQL, T-SQL, Oracle, etc. sections; where the examples would be identical, the text is included automatically from some common location. Would this duplicate a lot of material from use-the-index-luke while also removing helpful explanatory information? Probably, but that seems to be the idea behind Examples.SO. ;P

Comment: I think RegEx is slightly different in that it has no ANSI/[ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9075) (or any other) standard to serve as a base spec whereas SQL does

Comment: @DavidG That's not entirely correct (hence my "no one standard" wording). There is the [POSIX specs](http://www.wellho.net/regex/posix.html), but most engines don't follow it.

Comment: @Laurel Actually there are multiple POSIX standards and technically there's also the Perl standard (and others of course.) All the major SQL databases offer some level of ANSI SQL compliance though. This is why we could have a base ANSI level SQL tag in docs that should apply to most situations.

Comment: @DavidG Hence: "no one standard". I'm not sure what angle you're getting at; this says more about the regex tag than SQL. It would actually be easier to write the SQL docs, since there is a standard to use as the "base". Not that I'm going to give up on the regex docs, either...

Comment: I mean that if there is no single standard, then you have nothing to base it on. Your answer suggests it is the same for SQL but if the topic was renamed "ANSI SQL" then I don't think it can be applied in the same way. I applaud your resilience inside the RegEx docs though, hopefully that will be made easier when they implement the multiple-language-tabbing-feature-thingummy.

Comment: @DavidG I was actually recommending *against* renaming the topic (which would likely be its death sentence). It would cover the standard, of course, but it would also be documenting "what is the X Version of this code in Y Version?"

Answer (score 2):

My two cents for a possible solution:

List all technologies that support SQL at the top of topics list and make users first select their technology before viewing anything. This will auto force them (beginners) to recognize the technology they are using and save them grief when looking at examples that won't translate directly into their environments. (This solves one of the problems highlighted in the question)

Also have a general tab where users can learn and view examples about SQL in general.

Topics and examples will then automatically filter based on what has been tagged what technology and they will only see examples/topics that have been tagged as pertaining to selected technology.

We can use the same methodology for creating topics/examples as well, where we click into a technology before we can add examples.

Also, since this problem applies to only some tags (like SQL & Regex), you can make this feature (maybe called "Request Filters for this Tag") a voted feature.

Also, thinking more about this, you may want to use the same logic for filtering examples based on versions (i.e. SQL Server 2014/ 2012..) since examples are bound to get longer and longer with future versions.

Comment: "filtering examples based on versions" this is exactly the point. Does it make sense to have long examples everywhere because the code may be totally different between versions of the same language? The first and most simple [PHP docs array example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-99) has 2 different "versions", and oh, what a surprise, in PHP 7 you can now define ["constant arrays"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_constant_arrays.htm).