# Filtering/switching documentation examples based on language version

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Does it make sense to have extended examples because the code may be considerably different between versions of the same language?

This problem was raised in [one of the answers of the SQL documentation question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330220/6225838) and the solution seems simple, a filter (or a dropdown at the top of the page) could allow people to select which version the example refers to.

Not really complaining about any particular language, but the [first and most simple PHP docs array example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-99) depicts 2 different "versions", and in PHP 7, non-surprisingly, it is now possible to define ["constant arrays"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_constant_arrays.htm).

Answer (score 4):

This is a very similar feature that is planned but not currently implemented.  From the [Documentation open beta announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328405/documentation-has-entered-public-beta) "What's to come" section at the bottom of the post:

> There are things we know we’re going to do that just weren’t ready in
>   time for launch.
>
> - Code blocks with multiple languages (think MSDN’s C#/VB/F# switcher)

Multi-language tabs could potentially be a solution to multiple version of the same language.

Comment: It may not be as user-friendly, because the whole surrounding text will remain (despite being obsolete), and the example will still occupy some place on the screen. Also, just because you are asking for XX 7 examples does not mean that XX 6 or XX 5 are necessarily obsolete; examples can be relevant to a range of versions... and I don't see how handling that either with the multi-languages.