# Skip button on Documentation review?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation

I got some notifications for review. I checked them and found that there is no Skip button but only Approve and Reject.

Comment: Since there is no Documentation review "queue" that records and tracks your reviewing activity the same way the review queues do on Q&A, there's no need for a skip button. You already have to go back to the Dashboard page to review another proposed edit, so just continue that behavior by leaving the page if you don't want to approve or reject.

Comment: The notifications can be just ignored...

Comment: Please stop posting feature-requests for things that are plainly in [the next update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329557/5743988). It's not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An updated review queue is planned in the [latest Documentation update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th#329624).

All the particular details are still being ironed out.