# Edit button on documentation review?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, documentation

While reviewing I see that there is something that should be improved slightly. But currently I have to approve and then go and edit. The review queue of stackoverflow is better than of documentation.

Comment: Needs consideration of other options as well like *"Approve with Improvement Request"*. Not as cut and dry as Q/A approvals

Answer (score 1):

An update to the review queue that is more similar to the one in Q&A was announced here: [Documentation Update, July 25th](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th)