# Split example to multiple examples retaining original author/contributors

Tags: feature-request, documentation

There should be a way to split large example to multiple ones retaining all original author/contributors on such newly created examples.

That would allow reorganization of topics without losing rightful attribution and reputation gains for those that have contributed to creating/editing.

Comment: I think we _do_ need to do something along those lines. We're tackling the too many examples in a topic problem [first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th), however.